# Difference between _mm256_cvtxps_ph and _mm256_cvtps_ph?

Tags: avx512

I'm really confused by the _mm256_cvtps_ph and _mm256_cvtxps_ph intrinsics.  Intel says:

**__m128h _mm256_cvtxps_ph (__m256 a)** Convert packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in a to packed half-precision (16-bit) floating-point elements, and store the results in dst.

**__m128i _mm256_cvtps_ph (__m256 a, int imm8)**  Convert packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in a to packed half-precision (16-bit) floating-point elements, and store the results in dst. Rounding is done according to the imm8[2:0] parameter

So both do the same thing, except I can set the rounding mode in _mm256_cvtps_ph ?  Testing it, this does not seem to be the case:

```
union U256f {
    __m256 v;
    float a[8];
};

void print256_f16(const __m256h v)
{
    //printf doesn't support fp16, so convert to fp32
    __m512 fp32 = _mm512_cvtph_ps((__m256i)v);

    const U512f u = { fp32 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        printf("%f\n", u.a[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    __m256 constant_two = _mm256_set1_ps(2.0);

    printf("Input YMM register:\n");
    print256_f32(constant_two);

    __m128h cvtxps = _mm256_cvtxps_ph(constant_two);
    __m128h cvtps = _mm256_cvtps_ph(constant_two, _MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT);

    printf("_mm256_cvtxps_ph:\n");
    print128_f16(cvtxps);

    printf("_mm256_cvtps_ph:\n");
    print128_f16(cvtps);
}
```

Prints:

```
Input YMM register:
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
_mm256_cvtxps_ph:
-0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
_mm256_cvtps_ph:
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
2.000000
```

Since I'm getting garbage out for _mm256_cvtxps_ph, how is it supposed to be used?

Edit:

The code above was compiled in clang, but VS2012 and Intel C compiler produce the same output.  Here is the disassembly from clang:

```
    __m128h cvtxps = _mm256_cvtxps_ph(constant_two);
00007FF631F41DF7  vcvtps2phx  xmm0,ymmword ptr [rbp+40h]  
00007FF631F41DFE  movdqa      xmmword ptr [rbp+1C0h],xmm0  
00007FF631F41E06  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rbp+1C0h]  
00007FF631F41E0E  movdqa      xmmword ptr [cvtxps],xmm0  
    __m128h cvtps = _mm256_cvtps_ph(constant_two, _MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT);
00007FF631F41E13  vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [constant_two]  
00007FF631F41E18  vcvtps2ph   xmm0,ymm0,0  
00007FF631F41E1E  movdqa      xmmword ptr [rbp+1F0h],xmm0  
00007FF631F41E26  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [rbp+1F0h]  
00007FF631F41E2E  movdqa      xmmword ptr [cvtps],xmm0
```

Looking at the intrinsics guide, these are the expected instructions.

Comment: What gcc version and what hardware do you have?  I can't find an option to enable the cvtxps instructions.

Comment: `vcvtps2phx  xmm0,ymmword ptr [rbp+40h]` - did clang earlier copy `[constant_two]` to the stack?  It didn't do that with `vcvtps2ph`.  Also, how did you get clang to emit `vmovups` for some instructions but legacy-SSE encodings of `movdqa` in the same function?  If AVX is enabled, GCC and clang use VEX encoding for every instruction that supports it.  (Doesn't look like a correctness problem, though.)

Comment: Or is `[constant_two]` actually a local variable that your disassembler is inventing a symbol name for?  Like with `[cvtps]` which also isn't a global in static storage.  Anyway it's odd that this debug build (?) isn't loading from the original `[constant_two]` for the `x` version.

Answer (score 2):

The non-`x` conversion asm instructions were new in F16C (conversion only), since Ivy Bridge.
The `x` versions were new in AVX512-FP16 (includes FP16 math), since Sapphire Rapids.

In the intrinsics API, the old F16C intrinsics use `__m128i` (treating it as an integer vector), but AVX-512FP16 intrinsics introduce a new vector type, `__m128h` / `__m256h` / `__m512h`.

---

According to the asm manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtph2ps:vcvtph2psx and https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtps2ph vs. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtps2phx), the new `VCVTPH2PSX` (AVX512-FP16) can use a 16-bit broadcasted memory operand as a source, unlike the non-x version.

The `x` version of `PS` to `PH` supports a rounding override in the EVEX prefix (for 512-bit destination only, thus 256-bit source), as well as 32-bit broadcast source.  The VEX-encoding of the non-`x` version (`VCVTPS2PH`) are the same code-size as EVEX `VCVTPS2PHX`, since it requires a 3-byte VEX prefix + immediate vs. 4-byte EVEX.

The only reason to have a different intrinsic for the `x` version of PH to PS is that some compilers let you use intrinsics without enabling the instruction sets (notoriously MSVC which only provides a `/arch:AVX512` without any way to specify which specific AVX-512 extensions). And there's no intrinsic that takes a pointer, so it's up to the compiler to fold a load like `_mm_set1_ph(_Float16)` or `_mm_set1_epi16(short)` into a memory source operand instead of a separate `vpbroadcastw` or something.  But MSVC wouldn't know it was allowed to do that if there was only the old intrinsic which didn't imply anything beyond AVX-512BW or just AVX1+F16C

MSVC also apparently doesn't support `_mm_set1_ph` yet. (As discussed in comments on [AVX512-FP16 intrinsics fails in release mode, works in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616990/avx512-fp16-intrinsics-fails-in-release-mode-works-in-debug))

---

MSVC has at least some bugs with AVX512-FP16 support, again see *[AVX512-FP16 intrinsics fails in release mode, works in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616990/avx512-fp16-intrinsics-fails-in-release-mode-works-in-debug)*.

Your code works fine when compiled with GCC ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:25,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:25,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:25,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:25,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aunion+U256f+%7B%0A++++__m256+v%3B%0A++++float+a%5B8%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+print128_f16(const+__m128h+v)%0A%7B%0A++++//printf+doesn!%27t+support+fp16,+so+convert+to+fp32%0A++++__m256+fp32+%3D+_mm256_cvtph_ps((__m128i)v)%3B%0A%0A++++const+U256f+u+%3D+%7B+fp32+%7D%3B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+8%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25f%5Cn%22,+u.a%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++__m256+constant_two+%3D+_mm256_set1_ps(2.0)%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22Input+YMM+register:%5Cn%22)%3B%0A//++++print256_f32(constant_two)%3B%0A%0A++++__m128h+cvtxps+%3D+_mm256_cvtxps_ph(constant_two)%3B%0A++++__m128i+cvtps+%3D+_mm256_cvtps_ph(constant_two,+_MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT)%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22_mm256_cvtxps_ph:%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++print128_f16(cvtxps)%3B%0A%0A++++printf(%22_mm256_cvtps_ph:%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++print128_f16((__m128h)cvtps)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:39.37801138852387,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dsapphirerapids%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.87046632124353,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:35.129533678756474,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:60.62198861147613,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)), after fixing it to use 256-bit vectors like your `main` expects, and stuff like that, and commend out the call to the missing `print256_f32`.   After GCC's done optimizing, it only uses `vcvtps2ph`, not the `x` version, so it runs on older CPUs including the AWS instances Godbolt runs on, despite compiling with `-march=sapphirerapids`.

This is a missed-optimization; it could I think assume the MXCSR rounding mode and use `VCVTPS2PHX xmm, DWORD PTR .LC3[rip]` instead of a separate `vbroadcastss`.  (Even with `-ffast-math` it misses that optimization.)

But anyway, it's probably just MSVC being buggy again if you're using MSVC.  It obviously has FP16 bugs, so use a better compiler like GCC or Clang.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I missed that one was F16C, so that makes a bit more sense. After your help with the FP16 issue, I switched to clang, which I used for the above code (although VS gives the same result).  I wonder if there is some errata with vcvtps2phx on Alder Lake?  It officially had AVX512 support disabled just before launch, so I suppose not many people have used the more obscure instructions.

Comment: @user1850479: Can you provide an actual [mcve] of a full program that gives unexpected results with clang?  I may have fixed something without realizing it when adapting the code in your question to actually compile (the Godbolt link in my answer).  As I said, the way I compiled resulted in a program with no run-time use of `VCVTPS2PHX`, just constant-propagation.  With a MCVE, we can see if the same machine code works differently in SDE on a simulated sapphire rapids; only then do we have to consider Alder Lake's unofficial AVX-512 support being not fully working.