# inlining failed in call to always_inline '__mm512d'

Tags: c, simd, avx

I am trying to compile a simple C code using matrix multiplication and Simd instructions but I am getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ6LZ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post your full `g++` command and the full output from it as text, not as an image, so it's easier for people to copy it or search for it.  I think you should also work on simplifying your code and provide it as a [mcve] so that others can easily see the error happening on their own systems.

Comment: You need to enable AVX512 when compiling. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654290/error-inlining-failed-to-call-always-inline

Comment: See also [What exactly do the gcc compiler switches (-mavx -mavx2 -mavx512f) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71229343)